# Is it possible to fetch data from mysql database table from a particular id to a particular id?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Suppose there are 100 entries in a table and the need is to fetch data from id 3 to id 7 ( means data from 5 id(s), leaving the id 1 & 2).
Is it possible to do so using php mysql?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. You can put a condition to do so: SELECT * from table where id BETWEEN 3 AND 7

Comment: No. It will show the values of all rows with id between 3 and 7. Possibly 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7. If you want 3 and seven you can do: SELECT * from table where id=3 or id=7

Comment: id 3 to 7 doesn't mean 5 ids. It just means ids greater than or equal to 3, and less than or equal to 7. There might be 5. There might be fewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of searching in a range of numbers something like this can help.

```
select * from test where id between 3 and 7;
```

Which is similar to this

```
select * from test where id >= 3 and id <=7;
```

In case you want results from 3 to 7 but without `id` number 6 then something like this can also help.

```
select * from test where id in (3,4,5,7);
```

And again the above query can be re-writen to this

```
select * from test where id >= 3 and id <=7 and id<>6;
```

Check also this example on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/989351/5) where you could also check the time needed for the query result.